# TeeChart printing Labels scalling issues after Update to Delphi 10.2 Tokyo

Tags: delphi, printing, delphi-2009, teechart, delphi-10.2-tokyo

After Update Delphi 2009 to Delphi 10.2 Tokyo when printing Charts the labeling looks like crushed or false scaled. On Screen all looks ok and on print the Chart himself looks also good, only the Labels are not good.
For printing we use the TPrinter and  printpartial method from teechart to print more Charts together in the same page.
We nothing changes on the source Code.

Version of TeeChart: 9.0.1.0
Printing-Method: PrintPartial

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4j7i.png): [image: Difference between Delphi2009 and Delphi10.2 TChart.Print]

Someone with the same Problems or maybe a solution? Thanks

Comment: Could you please arrange a simple example project we can run as-is to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @Yeray Some ideas to this i writen down in the answer below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Yeray for answer.
I found the issues by changing between many times D2009 and D10.2.

If none Default Canvas is set (D2009) the print will be good.
After saving (D10.2) the Tchart will change the "DefaultCanvas = 'TGDIPlusCanvas'", the print is not good.
If i set the Canvas in source Code to "Chart1.Canvas := TTeeCanvas3D.Create" the print is good.

So what Kind of Canvas do you prefer for printing? Do i have to change the canvas before every printing? The TGDIPlusCanvas looks better on Screen than TTeeCanvas3D.

Thanks

Comment: TeeChart 2013.09 moved the default Canvas from GDI to GDIPlus so that could explain why you notice a difference between D2009 and D10.2. You save the canvas in use, force GDI canvas for printing and restore the original canvas as explained [here](http://www.teechart.net/support/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=12444&hilit=%2Agdiplus%2A+%2Aprintpartial%2A&start=15#p55242). However, we'd be glad to take a look at any example you could send so we can check what's wrong when printing with GDIPlus